# Rails: How Rails creates params hash from the input data submitted from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am experimenting with for submission. below is my form. when i am submitting this form then rails is generating params hash as `{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "users"=>[{"id"=>"a", "name"=>"b"}, {"id"=>"c", "name"=>"d"}], "commit"=>"Save "}`

```
<%= form_with do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field "users[][][][][id]" %>
    <%= form.text_field "users[][][][][name]" %>
    <%= form.text_field "users[][id]" %>
    <%= form.text_field "users[][name]" %>              
    <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But when i am submitting same form by reversing the order of text field elements as shown below then why rails is generating params as `{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "users"=>[{"id"=>"c", "name"=>"d"}], "commit"=>"Save "}` ??

```
<%= form_with do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field "users[][id]" %>
    <%= form.text_field "users[][name]" %>  
    <%= form.text_field "users[][][][][id]" %>
    <%= form.text_field "users[][][][][name]" %>            
    <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Why rails is not considering input values `a and b` provided to elements
`<%= form.text_field "users[][id]" %> <%= form.text_field "users[][name]" %>` respectively in the above form when forming hash params??

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to understand how rake parses parameters.

- Opne irb
- Enter following code

```rb
require "rack"

query_string = "users[][][][][id]=a&users[][][][][name]=b&users[][id]=c&users[][name]=d"
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(query_string)
=> {"users"=>[{"id"=>"a", "name"=>"b"}, {"id"=>"c", "name"=>"d"}]}

query_string = "users[][id]=a&users[][name]=b&users[][][][][id]=c&users[][][][][name]=d"
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(query_string)
=> {"users"=>[{"id"=>"c", "name"=>"d"}]}
```

Rails reads the query parameters from left to right in the query-string, and creates a new object each time it sees a repeated attribute.

Also, when the field name ends with empty square brackets, the parameter is treated as an empty array, and values get appended to it.

Refer this blog [Rails Parameters Parsing and the Case of Parameters Corruption](https://blog.kiprosh.com/rails-parameters-parsing-and-the-case-of-parameters-corruption/)
  to understand this concept thoroghly.